# Can a WP7.1 app use UdpAnySourceMulticastClient to communicate with Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

Can UdpAnySourceMulticastClient be used in a WP7.1 app to communicate with Android and iOS?  If it is possible is there any limitations on the datasize that can be transferred?

Answer (score 0):

There is no restriction on the type of sender (or receiver) to receive the UDP datagram from. The API only gives the IP Address of the sender and not the type. There is usually limit on the size since it is a datagram, after all